# For Loop Taking Too Long - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file which has two sheets where Sheet 1 has 5k records and Sheet 2 has 170k records. I am trying to perform a VLOOKUP in Sheet 2 (based on the values from column A). On top the value returned by the vlookup I am trying to to verify a few conditions to create a flag (Pass/Fail/Not Available/Not Applicable)

Here's the code that I have tried so far:

```
Public Sub Validation()

With Workbooks("Macro.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
    maxrows = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row             
    maxCols = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   
    Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(maxrows, maxCols))
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Workbooks("Macro.xlsm").Worksheets(2).Activate
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    cellvalue = Range("A" & i).Value
 'Logic for V1
    RES_V1 = Application.VLookup(cellvalue, Data, 2, 0)
    If IsError(RES_V1) Then
        V1 = "Not Available"
    ElseIf UCase(RES_V1) Like "30 DAYS*" Or UCase(RES_V1) Like "60 DAYS*" Or UCase(RES_V1) = "NO SA" Then
        V1 = "Pass"
    ElseIf UCase(RES_V1) = "NOT APPLICABLE" Then
        V1 = "Not Applicable"
    Else
        V1 = "Fail"
    End If
    
    Cells(i, "B").Value = V1
Next i
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This process is taking too long to execute and most of the times the excel either crashes or does not respond. I have tried using the basic "With" statement and applying this logic. In addition I have also tried turning the For loop into For Each thinking that it might be faster. Neither of these helped. Any suggestions with regards to re-writing the code or tweaking the existing code to fix the issue alongside improve the performance is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try storing the last row into a variable ahead of time and using that instead of making it part of your `For` statement. But most likely it's your VLookup causing it to be slow. You may benefit from using a Dictionary instead of a VLookup.

Comment: My bad, i forgot including that point. I did try storing the lastrow in a variable, but that did not help. Thanks :)

Comment: And you tried a dictionary?

Comment: Nope, I haven't worked on dictionaries earlier, will give it a try.

Comment: What kind of variable is `Data`? it's looks like a `Variant` so line `Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(maxrows, maxCols))` will store the values, but not create a reference to range. Also, if all your values are always in column 2, then you could just take `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(maxrows, 2))`. But something like `RES_V1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cellvalue, Workbooks("Macro.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(maxrows, 2)), 2, 0)` should work

Comment: Yes, the variable Data is of type variant. Also, as you rightly said, it was just storing values looks like, will try to update and test the code and will revert to you..

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, I updated the lookup function as you said. It worked. Thanks for the help. However, I have 7 such validations (like V1 shown above) and it is taking 6 Minutes for the code to execute successfully.. Any suggestions on further optimization?

Comment: Have you tried executing line by line with F8? Also, have you tried adding `Application.EnableEvents=False?` Anyways, 170k records are a lot. Try `Select Case` instead of severla ifs.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns Hello, that's True, 170K records are a lot. However, I am already working on converting the if-else blocks to Case statement now.. I will keep you posted about the performance results. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I just wanted to provide an update on the problem - I have converted all the if-lse blocks into Case statements. However, it seems like the execution time is still going upto ~10 Minutes now.